# How to end node js execution in case of a API usage error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently writing a node js library. Now I came up with the question what would be the best approach to indicate a usage error by the programmer.

For example if I got the following function in my public API:

```
function doSomething(aNumber) {
    // ...
}
```

and I need to make sure that aNumber actually is a number, what way of error handling should I go if the API user passes a parameter that is not.

By convetion functions in node should return an Error object if an error occurs. But in my case this is no error the programmer should catch.

So my question is what would be the most appropriate way to maybe simply "end" the program with an error message, telling the programmer that he did not use my API in the correct way.

Comment: throw an exception? Surely if they pass in the wrong thing then that is an error (of sorts)?

Comment: For me an exception always means an error that is catchable and treatable. Is wrong API usage really something one needs to catch?

Comment: Not all exceptions are treatable at runtime. and passing an invalid type is an exception over being an error. Either way, you should at least return an err.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do the following:

```
console.log("Incorrect api usage.");
process.exit(-1);
```

You may want to wrap that in a helper function to make the calls simpler...

Comment: Why should an error in one function kill the entire process? this is bad!

Comment: Why is this bad? Wrong API usage means not runnable at all.

Comment: Because by forcing the process to exit, you are removing any decision making capability from end users of the library, it could be that they might want to keep in running despite the failure incurred in your module.

Comment: @James: I agree completely, however was just going with the author's question "By convetion functions in node should return an Error object if an error occurs. But in my case this is no error the programmer should catch."